# Condition for a matrix to have anticommutator

Tags: linear-algebra

For a $N\times N$ complex matrix $M$, what's the necessary condition for the existence of a non-zero anti-commutator $N$, such that $\{M,N\}=MN+NM=0$ $?$

Is there a necessary and sufficient condition $?$

And I also wonder the necessary condition for a $N\times N$ complex matrix $P$ to have a non-zero commutator $Q$, such that $[P,Q]=PQ-QP=0$.

Comment: We can always take $N=0$. Then $\{M,0\}=0$.

Comment: yes, but it's a sufficient condition.

Comment: It is also sufficient. Every matrix $M$ has an anticommutator (see your title question).

Comment: I see, let me change my question a bit.

Comment: Regarding the second question: every non-zero $P$ has a non-zero commutator, namely $Q=P$.

Comment: The second question is answered completely [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92480/given-a-matrix-is-there-always-another-matrix-which-commutes-with-it?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the condition that $M$ is nilpotent is sufficient. Let $k$ be the smallest positive integer with $M^k=0$. Then we may take $N=M^{k-1}\neq 0$ to obtain
$$
MN+NM=M^k+M^k=0.
$$
On the other hand, the example $M=I$ shows that there may be no nonzero anticommuting matrix $N$. Suppose first that $M$ is invertible. Then $MN+NM=0$ implies
$$
N=M^{-1}(-N)M
$$
so that $N$ and $M$ are similar. In particular, $N$ must have trace zero.
If both $M$ and $N$ are invertible, taking determinants we obtain $\det(N)\det(M)=(-1)^n\det(N)\det(M)$, hence $1=(-1)^n$, which gives the necessary condition that $n$ is even, and that $tr(N)=tr(M)=0$.

In general there is a lot of literature on anticommutaing matrices, which might help in giving necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a non-trivial anticommuting matrix to a given one. As a start, see the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767232/maximum-number-of-linearly-independent-anti-commuting-matrices).

Comment: Yes, even dimension restriction is truly a necessary condition I am looking for. But this restriction is coarse, the finer restrictions are more helpful.