# Abelian subalgebra doesn't imply toral

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L $ be a Lie algebra. A subalgebra $H$ of $L$ such that $ad_H:\frak g → g$ is diagonalizable for every $h ∈ H$ is called toral.

Now, every toral subalgebra is abelian. But, what is an example for an abelian subalgebra which is not toral?

Answer (score 2):

Take any element $x\in L$ that is not semisimple and let $H$ be the span of $x$.

Comment: A larger expample (a maximal one, indeed!), the space of matrices described by David [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42412/large-sets-of-commuting-linearly-independent-matrices).

Comment: As a complementary of my question I am looking for 3 dimensional non-nilpotent Lie algebra whose only toral subalgebra is 0. In $sl_2$ the element  $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ is diagonalizable so the space generated by it is toral.. What about $\mathbb R^3 $,$^$?

Answer (score 1):

To give an explicit non-semisimple example, consider the
Lie algebra  $L=\mathfrak{r}_3(\mathbb{C})$, given by the Lie brackets
$$
[e_1,e_2]=e_2,\; [e_1,e_3]=e_2+e_3.
$$
We have 
$$
ad(e_1)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This matrix is not diagonalizable, so that $\mathfrak{t}=\langle e_1\rangle$ is an abelian subalgebra, which is not toral.